# Dynamic language menu switching (if/else) based on is_dir

Tags: php, directory

I'm trying to switch dynamically a language menu in index.php, but it's not working.

What is wrong with the following code:

```
  $dir = "/en";

  if (! is_dir($dir)){
  include ('/menu/de.php');
  }else{
  include ('/menu/en.php');
  }
```

Based on previous suggestions, i also tried with

```
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/en';

if ( !is_dir(dirname(__FILE__).$dir)){

include ('/menu/de.php');
}else{
include ('/menu/en.php');
}
```

But with or without the ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], only one the de.php menu is showing up, also in the subdirectory /en.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Do this instead `include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/menu/de.php');` and `include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/menu/en.php');` - it worked for me.

Comment: `$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/en';` `if ( !is_dir(dirname($dir)) ) {` ...

Comment: Fred ii: With this code i get an _failed to open stream: No such file or directory_ error :-(

Comment: @tttony I just tried it; now i get the menu in english, but not the de.menu :-((. It seems that there's something wrong with the if/else statement, but i cannot see where

Comment: While using `$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/en';` and not `$dir = "/en";`

Comment: DOCUMENT_ROOT because the path has to be relative. But also without it it's not working :-((.